# Which statement is memory/processor efficient ?

Tags: php, memory-management, processing-efficiency

I don't have better why to rephrase the question , you might suggest me one. Most of the time I re-use a variable in php I wonder, which one will be memory/processor efficient . e.g

**case A**

```
 $string_var ='1,2,4,5,6,7,8';
 $array_var  =explode(',',$string_var);
```

**Case B**: re-use the same variable (string variable and re-declare as array object)

```
 $array_var ='1,2,4,5,6,7,8';
 $array_var  =explode(',',$array_var);
```

My question is not from code-readability point of view . I wonder which one will be efficient way in term of memory and processor utilization.

Comment: You could always run a micro-benchmark...

Comment: Post this question to codereview

Comment: What's the point in optimizing one of the fastest parts of your code?

Comment: optimize for readability, unless performance / memory is really an issue

Comment: @jon, my question is regarding single statement not  whole function .

Comment: @Starx can you point me to `codereview`, sorry I am unaware of this

Comment: @sakhunzai: What I 'm trying to say is that the difference is going to be so small it's not worth talking about.

Comment: @Jon that is true in above case.But what will happen when we use either type of assignment within the loop . Obviously one of the technique should be BETTER and it should have a reason for that. Thanks for your comments :)

Comment: Its http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" (Knuth) http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string_var ='1,2,4,5,6,7,8';
$array_var  =explode(',',$string_var);
```

This will keep both the string and the array in memory, using more memory. If you'd overwrite the original variable, the previously stored content would be garbage collected at some point, freeing up memory. In practice it may not make any real difference, since the values won't be garbage collected immediately, and if your variables are reasonably scoped they should go out of scope soon enough anyway.

It makes virtually no difference in *processing time*.

Go with what makes more sense logically. If you don't need `$string_var` anymore, there's no need to keep it around as a separate variable. Try to declutter your namespace as much as possible.

Comment: what do you mean by `Try to declutter your namespace` ? Do you mean unset unwanted variables ?

Comment: Use the least amount of variables, identifiers, constants, functions etc. you can get away with. More variables means more chances for bugs and confusion and inefficiencies.

Comment: yes you're right , how we can test that ist variable is  `garbage collected`  100% of time , @mensi is not proponent of that idea ( see answer one  comments )

Comment: You do not have 100% control over PHP's garbage collection. And neither do you need to. Garbage collection is there so you **don't** have to worry about memory and can write less code. You can play around with [`gc_collect_cycles`](http://php.net/gc_collect_cycles), but ultimately it's up to PHP to manage memory. What you can do is reduce the variables in use so PHP knows it can garbage collect the data associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you create a new variable, a bit of memory is allocated to that variable. Therefore 2 variables will take around twice as much memory. It is better to use the same variable **Case B** as that only uses the memory required for 1 variable.

Comment: This is not entirely true, since garbage collection might happen much later.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them will affect the processor in same manner. Though, there will be lower memory usage in the **Case B** as you'll be updating an existing variable to a new array.

Answer (score 0):

If this wasn't PHP, but a "lower level" language like C, the answer would be quite simple:

1. will be slightly more efficient in speed (directly rewrite results to destination location in memory, skip rewriting the pointer)
2. will be slightly more efficient in matter of memory (temporary location holding the result between right-side and left-side of the operation deallocated immediately after operation, just one variable allocated permanently.)

With PHP being a scripted language, all I can say B might be marginally more memory-conservative in the long run, but the amount is really insignificant. Other than that, all bets are off, write a benchmark.